# How can I survey the customers of my clients?

Tags: user-research, research, surveys

We're a SaaS company providing web and mobile apps for our clients. Their customers use our product, but they don't know we exist as a company. Now that I'm on board as a designer; I would like their feedback and thoughts consistently.

Naturally I would need to loop in our clients for something like this, but does anyone have experience with how to go about surveying in this situation?

I would ideally like to not just have the survey in app, but also the option to send surveys via email.

Comment: So your company designs and develops the app for your clients, but does it also provide the customer support? If so then you have another channel of feedback about the product. What about all the usual channels like the product review and building a feedback mechanism directly into the app?

Answer (score 1):

*(disclaimer: I have some assumption about your sitation, but i cant comment to your question for clarification)*

**METHOD01:**

**Recruit a representative pool from all your client's users**

*This method doesn't need collaboration from your client. You will be in control, but needs more effort for the same sample size and quality.*

1. Analyze the user base size of the apps where your service is present
2. Weight the recruitment effort according to the distribution
3. Define a representative pool for email surveys.
4. Design a survey. Make some low sample size pilots, for pivoting, optimizing.

   I guess the completion rate will be in between 10-30%. Of course, you can use motivation, like amazon coupons.

**METHOD02:**

**Collaboration with your most representative clients**

1. List all your clients and try to pick some, who represents the variety of your costumers the most.
2. Write some template emails to your clients market/UX researchers, asking them about their surveying routines (if any)
   Maybe the representative ones already surveying, so you will have the channel.
   And *maybe* they will be helpful and implement a survey for you.

**If not:**

- Try to convince them/their bosses with a short pitch about why its good to their product if your service will work better, thanks to a better understanding of your users.

**And the last chance:**

- The same pitch, to your boss, why he needs to give some discount to your client, for winning the cooperation :D

**METHOD03:**

**Expensive but simple solution**

- Outsource recruiting, create a screener and see if the researcher agency has enough potential participants.

Answer (score 0):

Your dev team can install on-page survey snippets, such as those provided by Hotjar.

Comment: Yes - currently they have a limited version of that, but it doesn't get a lot of traction. Different UX issue to address in that situation!

I haven't used hotjar previously - is that one you'd recommend exploring? My concern is there's no mobile support and our app gets more sessions.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to having an in-built survey in the app, is to have a support/issues website where their customers log complaints/feedback directly. The site can be labelled as your Clients, but your company runs it. Hence you have control on feedback. You can also have a means of logging an issue via the app.